# Creating a usable search for filtering

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, search, fuzzy-search, n-gram

i'm not well versed on the problem of search. 
I have only really used sql with like queries and in etc.

I need to create a search to filter files and products. So given the filename:
company_launch 2019.png

If you started to search any of the below as you would expect that file would be returned:

- com
- 2019
- launch
- lanch
- _launch
- .png

etc

This is for a laravel php site. I've looked at https://github.com/teamtnt/tntsearch however i couldn't get that to match better than the exact word / the word minus a few characters. There were also more edge cases that meant the above expected behaviour didn't work.

I am now looking at [elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html). I have a basic grasp of the concept of ngrams and how that would relate to searching part of a word, however i'm not sure if this + fuzzymatching is enough to achieve this search. So far i can only get exact matches as before.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to achieve a search which does what you would expect?

Comment: have you tried Algolia? https://www.algolia.com/

Comment: https://github.com/adnanmayo/laravel-elastic have a look at this written by me

Comment: Thanks Anan, but this has the same issue as i'm encountering. 
i.e there is a record with the title 'Aliquid commodi provident itaque quis velit'.

However searching this using 'liquid' doesn't return anything

Comment: Using ES you can achieve this, playing with your tokenizer and field mapping settings. First take a look on how works [NGram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) and then try to create a field with [Multiple fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/multi-fields.html) with different configurations of analyzers/tokenisers it would help you to get the best approach to your problem.

Comment: Hi @jordivador thanks, i've started setting this up. I'm not sure how to get ngrams working properly. 
For example 

event jack,
event jon,
event_jack 

if you search this with event jack i would like it to show in the order 

event jack,
event_jack,
event_jon

Comment: Yes , but in this case you need also to set up your analyser correctly, from example if you need that `event_jack` becomes searchable by `evevent` or `jack` you will need to use for ex. [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)

Without indexing your data, you can try different analyzers/tokenisers and check how your data will be in index using [/_analyze endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_explain_analyze.html)

Comment: Yeah i've tried using a standard analyser to match event_ to event_jack but it's not working either. Just kinda stabbing in the dark at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

[TNTSearch](https://github.com/teamtnt/tntsearch) has a nice feature to achieve a functionality similar to the searchbar in sublime text. By installing the package you'll have right away access to `fuzzyMatchFromFile` function.

Lets consider the case where you have a bunch of images located in a single folder and you want to add search functionality.

First, you would save the directory listing to a file. This can be done with a simple command like:

`find ./path/to/image/folder -type f -follow -print > image-files.txt`

In the `image-files.txt`each image will be on its own line

Next, you'll provide this file as the second argument to the `fuzzyMatchFromFile` function

```
$query = "someword";
$path = "/path/to/image-files.txt";
$searchResults = fuzzyMatchFromFile($query, $path);
```

The `$searchResults` array will contain the path of the file together with the score

If you have a file named `beautiful-image.png` you'll be able to search and find it also with `btfl-img.png`.

The above will work very fast for up to 100k records.

The algorithm checks if a [common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) exists between the query and file name, and if so it calculates the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between two vectors (the filename and query strings both are transformed to an vector). Also, if a substring
exists, it increases the score